# auto populated dropdown with AJAX in django issue

Tags: django, ajax

im working on a search form on diffrent tables, i have two tables called 'specialte' and 'option' both assosiated with a table called 'service', what i want is when i choose a 'service' from a dropdown, another dropdown is auto populated with both specialtes and options using AJAX, i tried what i found in the internet but nothins seems to work.
 this is my .models :

```
class Service(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 45, blank = False, null = False)
    departement = models.ForeignKey(Departement, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class Option(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 45, blank = False, null = False)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class Specialite(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 45, blank = False, null = False)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

this is my view:

```
def personnel(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('authentification')
    else:
        service_id = request.GET.get('service')
        a = Affectation.objects.all().prefetch_related()
        o = Option.objects.filter(service_id=service_id).order_by('value')
        s = Specialite.objects.filter(service_id=service_id).order_by('value')
        se = Service.objects.all().prefetch_related()
        context = {
            'affectation':a,
            'option':o,
            'specialite':s,
            'service':se
        }
        return render(request,'personnel/personnel.html',context)
```

this is the html code :

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput1">Service:</label>
            <select name="service" id="service" class="form-control">

                <option>...</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput1">Specialite:</label>
            <select name="specialite" id="specialite" class="form-control">
              {% for o in option%}
                <option>{{ o.value }}</option>
                {%endfor %}
              {% for s in specialite%}
                  <option>{{ s.value }}</option>
              {%endfor %}
                        </select>
              </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput1">Grade:</label>
            <input name="grade" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="grade">
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

this is my script:

```
$("#service").change(function () {
   var url = $("#personnel");  
   var serviceID = $(this).val(); 

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",                
     url: url,                    
     data: {
       'service': serviceID      
     },
     success: function (data) {    view function
       $("#specialite").html(data);  
     }
   });

 });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464834/jquery-iterating-a-ajax-response-list-and-populating-and-it-in-dropdown-list

Comment: is it a working code ??

Answer (score 0):

This site isn't a free code generator. This is meant to be an example to help you form your own ajax call.

It's a pretty standard ajax call. You send data to the view, generate a matching list of specialties and options based on the foreign key lookup, then use the ajax response to generate dynamically created options.

You should try researching ajax calls and dynamic drop down lists as there is plenty of information about those on this site. The link I posted in my comment should also help.

Let me know if you need help with a specific aspect of the function or get stuck on a part. I won't write all your code for you from scratch.

EDIT:

```
data.forEach(function(index, data_obj) {
    $("#specialite").append(new Option(data_obj, data_obj));
});
```

I'm assuming your value and text will be the same so you would use the same variable in both places. This might not be exactly what you want and you need to check the  id to make sure I got it correct, but it should help get you started.

Comment: i edited my question, and i put what i found, its still not working

Comment: You're going to need to use that data to populate your dropdown list. Jquery doesn't know that you want it to fill in the options unless you tell it.

Comment: i found in many places that they loop inside of the jquery code, is that what i should do to ?

Comment: Yes there is plenty of information out there about creating a dynamic drop down list by looping through a list. Make sure your ajax call is returning the correct list by alerting it on success

Comment: well, i've found some about that, but the problem is in how to manipulate the list of objects, it has to be done with python, is it possible to work with python inside jquery?

Comment: check my edit and see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: i tries to test with something basic like this "      success: function () {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
       $("#specialite").append(new Option('1', '2'));  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
     }" but it's still not working ! no option has been add